# Expected a key while parsing a block mapping

Tags: mapping

Error detected in pubspec.yaml:

```
 Error on line 48, column 4: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping.
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
flutter:
 uses-material-design: true
  assets:
 - images/googlelogo.png
```

Comment: Spaces in 'pubspec.yaml' are significant, there must be exactly two spaces before an asset (<space><space>- images/googlelogo.png  //in this case) and also all the properties must be in same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned yourself in the comment, indentation is important in pubspec.yaml file. It should be like this:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/googlelogo.png
```